# incorrect result display from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that has 4 records with a column _id that auto increments. When I run a query to get all records, it works but it doesn't echo out all the ids, it only points to the first rows and echos it four times. I am using PHP and MySQLi. Here is my code

Code for querying

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM att_table";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Code for display

```
do{
    echo result['_id'];
}while($query->fetch_assoc());
```

It outputs 1111 instead of 1234. Please what is wrong?

Comment: please don't use caps and coding/programming language in titles. The tags are enough. I edited your question respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fetching each of the 4 results, so it loops the appropriate number of times; but you're only assigning the fetched result to `$result` once, so that's the only `_id` value that gets echoed

```
do{
    echo $result['_id'];
}while($result = $query->fetch_assoc())
```

Comment: Please, how then do I make it work. I have been outputing results that way

Comment: `while($query->fetch_assoc());` <= semi-colon is a terminator. No error because that is, believe it or not a valid statement. It must be removed. `while($query->fetch_assoc()){...}`

Comment: oh and missing a `$` for `result['_id'];` - `result` is treated as a constant.

Comment: @ITECH-PLANET - No you haven't been doing it that way..... read my answer carefully

Comment: I have checked other codes I have, it same and they are working except this one. :(

Comment: `}while($result = $query->fetch_assoc())` is not the same as your `}while($query->fetch_assoc())`.... I'm assigning the fetched result to `$result`

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a foreach loop :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM att_table";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();

foreach($result as $data){
    echo $data['_id'];
}
```